# Show random image in javascript classes

Tags: javascript

```js
class Food {
    constructor() {
        this.x = Math.random() * (canvasWidth - 0) + 0;
        this.y = Math.random() * (canvasHeight - 0) + 0;
        this.width = 45;
        this.height = 45;
        this.image = new Image()
        this.image.src = Math.random('img/apple.png','img/frogs.png')
    }
/*   update() {
    } */
    draw() {
        ctx.drawImage(this.image, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
let food = new Food()

function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
;
    food.draw()
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

I am working with HTML canvas and in my food class, I am trying to pick between two images randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [the documentation for `Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to see how to use it. In short, though, you cannot just say `Math.random('img/apple.png','img/frogs.png')`, hoping it to choose randomly between the two.

`Math.random()` takes exactly zero arguments and returns a number between 0 and 1. So you could, for example:

```js
const myImg = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'img/apple.png' : 'img/frogs.png'

console.log(myImg)
```